# What does a pipe in a class definition mean?

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, typeclass, functional-dependencies

```
class (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w m | m -> w where 
   pass   :: m (a,w -> w) -> m a 
   listen :: m a -> m (a,w) 
   tell   :: w -> m ()
```

What is the meaning of the pipe above? The snippet comes from [here](http://www.haskell.org/all_about_monads/html/writermonad.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the "|" for in a Haskell class definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675655/whats-the-for-in-a-haskell-class-definition)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, it's a "[functional dependency](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_type_classes#Functional_dependencies)". In this case that means that `m` uniquely identifies `w` -- the type `m` determines the type `w`. ([This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies) may be a better link.)