# Syntax of MonadState typeclass declaration

Tags: haskell, typeclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the “|” for in a Haskell class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675655/whats-the-for-in-a-haskell-class-definition)

I'm pretty new to Haskell.  In the [documentation of MonadState](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Class.html) I see the following:

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    get :: m s
    put :: s -> m ()
```

What is the `| m -> s` syntax here?

Comment: Indeed it is.  I didn't find that question when searching SO.  It's hard to search for a "|" character when you don't know what it's called :)

Comment: Quite so. Though, incidentally, this requires a language extension, and if you tried compiling such a definition without any compiler flags GHC will say something like `Fundeps in class 'C' (Use -XFunctionalDependencies to allow fundeps)`. The module documentation also specifies the extensions needed. Something to keep in mind for figuring out how to search. :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a *functional dependency* or fundep for short. The syntax

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
```

means, that there is only one instance for each `m` or - in other words, that if `m` is known, the compiler can infer the type of `s` form that. Using fundeps makes coding a lot easier, because the compiler can infer much more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer.  I googled "Haskell functional dependency" and am now busy reading http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies, which hopefully will elaborate!