# What does `... | a b -> c` in typeclass declaration mean?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the “|” for in a Haskell class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675655/whats-the-for-in-a-haskell-class-definition)

In the following (from `Data.HList.HListPrelude`, how do I interpret the `| l l' -> l''` part?

```
class HAppend l l' l'' | l l' -> l''
 where
  hAppend :: l -> l' -> l''
```

And is it a part of standard Haskell (i.e. Haskell 2010) or an extension?

Answer (score 8):

It is an extension called [Functional Dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies) which you can spot in future by looking at the top of the file.

It essentially says `l''` is uniquely determined from `l` and `l'`.

It is required because `HAppend` is a multiparameter typeclass (which is also an extension).

Comment: That might sound a little snarky, but if it wasn't clear when he says "you probably could have figured out by looking at the top of the file." he is referring to the first line that is commonly something like: `{-# LANGUAGE ...some extentions... #-}`