# Wired type class definition

Tags: haskell

Could someone please explain it to me following type class definition

```
class (Monad m, Monad n) => MonadCompose m n s t | m -> s, n -> t, n s -> m where
```

What does `|`, `,` and `->` mean ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675655/whats-the-for-in-a-haskell-class-definition?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Those are [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies).

Each of the clauses separated by a `,` after the `|` says that one type can be determined by another.

For example `m -> s` says that they type `s` can be determined from `m`